# scale invariant face similarity metric

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, face-detection

I need some face similarity metric.
I know about PCA,LDA approaches that uses raw pixels data, but they are not scale invariant(I know that I can resize image but I think that's not good solution).
Maybe I need to use AAM,ASM aproaches?
But I'm interested in metric that gives me the greatest separability of faces.
At first I don't need automatic detection of metric features, for example imagine that I can mark all faces by hand.

Answer (score 4):

Haven't used them first hand but I'm pretty sure that [[SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform)] "Scale Invariant Feature Transform" is scale invariant. And I know that they are used, with great success, in face recognition.

Comment: can you provide example where it used in face detection/recognition task? for example if you try here http://www.ipol.im/pub/demo/my_affine_sift/ to upload 2 faces, it gives no good output.

Comment: as I said in the answer, I have never used it, but I know our teacher talked about it in a image recognition course. When I googled on it, it seemed to a couple of versions of the used for example FSIFT. Google is your friend, I only pointed in the right direction.